# Multiple Tablix Display in Report based on Parameter

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have designed a report that has Tablix called By Resource that displays data by a resource code and a second tablix called By Start Date that displays data by a start date.

I've added a parameter called ReportSelection and gave it available values of:

### By Resource

### By Start Date

In the By Resource tablix, I selected Show or hide based on an expression and then set expression for hidden formula is:  =IIF(Parameters!ReportSelection.Value="By Resource",TRUE,FALSE)

However, when I run the report and select By Resource, the By Resource tablix doesn't show up. The By Start Date tablix appears instead.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is for "hidden", which means your TRUE value means hide it. Swap the TRUE and FALSE around, and it'll work.